# Access object from callback angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have function of loadAllUsers() :

```
function loadAllUsers(callback) {      
        UniversalService.GetAll()
            .then(function (response) {
                $scope.users=response;
                if (callback) {
                    callback(response);
                }
            });
    }
```

and I use response here:

```
function setPage(page) {
        loadAllUsers(function (response) {
            if (response) {
                if (page < 1 || page > vm.pager.totalPages) {
                    return;
            }
            console.log(response);debugger;
            console.log(response.name);debugger;
            // get pager object from service
            vm.pager = PagerService.GetPager(10, page);

            // get current page of items
            vm.items = response.slice(vm.pager.startIndex, vm.pager.endIndex + 1); 
            } 
        });
    }
```

when I print `console.log(response)` I get:

`Object
email:"r@gmail.com"
id:2
name:"ss"
review:"sdvds"
surname:"dsv"`

But when I try to print `console.log(response.name)` I get undefined. Is it possible to access it somehow?

Comment: console.log(response.name) the line after console.log(response) ?

Comment: yes, console.log(response.name) is undefined

Comment: try what this prints console.log(JSON.stringify(response)) and post here